# Bitcoin Core on SD card

Tags: bitcoin-core, error, reindex

Running out of hard drive space, I bought a 256 GB SD card formatted with the FAT filesystem and moved my Bitcoin directory to it. After getting error messages I decided to delete it and redownload (don't worry wallet/keys are backed up). Now it has downloaded about 11 GB and crashes with an error message. I can initiate reindexing and it will proceed, until at some point it crashes again.

After the failed reindexing when I relaunch Bitcoin Core I get this message:

---

### MinGW Runtime Assertion

Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe
File: validation.cpp, Line 2322

### Expression: !setBlockIndexCandidates.empty()

### Abort   Retry   Ignore

I have excluded the Bitcoin directory from on-access antivirus scanning, thinking maybe that was interfering but I am still getting this problem.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get Core fully online again? Could the use of flash media for storage of the database be contributing to the problem?

Comment: After reinstalling Bitcoin Core and initiating reindexing it appears to have been running continuously for over 12 hours without issue. Problem may have been resolved.